# Aligning only on one side, single line

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align

I would like to get something like this:
[image: example]

But if I write something like

```
\begin{equation}\label{key}
\begin{aligned}
\theta\left( c_1\ket{\alpha}+c_2\ket{\beta} \right)&=UK\left( c_1\ket{\alpha}+c_2\ket{\beta} \right)\\
&=c_1^\ast UK\ket{\alpha}+c_2^\ast UK\ket{\beta}\\
&=c_1^\ast\theta\ket{\alpha}+c_2^\ast\ket{\beta}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

outputs the aligned text  on the right aligned so that the middle of the alignment coincides with the arrow and the left text. Like this:
[image: output]

How can I change that?

And excuse the wording, explaining my idea was quite difficult

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You certainly do not have this result with the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very unclear but I think you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,braket}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{key}
\ket{\alpha}
\stackrel{K}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{aligned}[t]
\theta\left( c_1\ket{\alpha}+c_2\ket{\beta} \right)&=UK\left( c_1\ket{\alpha}+c_2\ket{\beta} \right)\\
&=c_1^\ast UK\ket{\alpha}+c_2^\ast UK\ket{\beta}\\
&=c_1^\ast\theta\ket{\alpha}+c_2^\ast\ket{\beta}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Too long for a comment.</sup>

The code snippet extended to a full MWE gives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{key}
  \begin{aligned}
    \theta\left( c_1\ket{\alpha}+c_2\ket{\beta} \right)
    &=UK\left( c_1\ket{\alpha}+c_2\ket{\beta} \right)\\
    &=c_1^\ast UK\ket{\alpha}+c_2^\ast UK\ket{\beta}\\
    &=c_1^\ast\theta\ket{\alpha}+c_2^\ast\ket{\beta}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The aligning is correct and there is no arrow, no summation signs, ...